# Playing Audio in Xcode7

Tags: xcode, swift, button, audio

I'm simply trying to play audio when I tap a button, but I get an error with this line of code.

```
ButtonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL, error: nil)
```

This is my whole code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var ButtonAudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Audio File 1", ofType: "mp3")!)

var ButtonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    ButtonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL, error:       nil)

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func playAudio1(sender: UIButton) {


}

}
```

The error is

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'contentsOfURL:error:', expected 'contentsOfURL:fileTypeHint:').

When I change error to fileTypeHint, it still does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the new Swift 2 syntax by changing that line to

```
ButtonAudioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL)
```

Comment: One thing to note with this approach, From the documentation: you can write try! before the expression to disable error propagation and wrap the call in a runtime assertion that no error will be thrown. If an error actually is thrown, you’ll get a runtime error.

Comment: Thank you so much! When I tap the button rapidly, there is a little bit of lag time. Do you know how to make it play when I tap it instantly?

Answer (score 1):

The AVAudioPlayer class can throw an error, You need to take this into consideration. I personally prefer a do statement which gives the opportunity to catch and handle the error.

This code worked fine for me:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let ButtonAudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "mp3")!)

    let ButtonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        do {
            ButtonAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL, fileTypeHint: ".mp3")

            ButtonAudioPlayer.play()
        } catch let error {
            print("error loading audio: Error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

You could also make this to an optional, like this:

```
ButtonAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL, fileTypeHint: ".mp3")
ButtonAudioPlayer?.play()
```

Using this method it will only attempt to play the file if no error was thrown in the previous statement, but will prevent a runtime error.